# how to convert byte array to integer?

Tags: java, javasound, pcm, wave

I have a byte array which contains pure sound data. I want to convert it to integer. bit per sample is 16. frame rate is 44100. but how to convert it into an integer?

Comment: You need to be more precise.  Converting a byte array containing sound data into "an integer" makes no sense.

Comment: A question for you: your byte array contains 16bit samples, but are they signed or unsigned?

Comment: And what byte order while we're at it? Is it PCM or something else?

Comment: it is pcm little endian and they are signed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clearify: You have a `byte[]` that contains pairs of `byte`'s to form an integer? So like this: `{int1B1, int1B2, int2B1, int2B2, int3B1, int3B2, ...}`?

If so, you can assemble them to integers like this:

```
int[] audio = new int[byteArray.length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length/2; i++) { // read in the samples
  int lsb = byteArray[i * 2 + 0] & 0xFF; // "least significant byte"
  int msb = byteArray[i * 2 + 1] & 0xFF; // "most significant byte"
  audio[i] = (msb << 8) + lsb;
}
```

Of course you can optimize that loop to a single line loop, but I prefer it that way for better readability. Also, depending on the endianness of the data, you can switch ub1 and ub2.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i dont understand the (ub2<<8) part. why is this necessary? thanks again. one other thing.. is this for little endian?

Comment: Well you save the bytes in `ub1` and `ub2`. Now we want to concatenate them to a 16bit value. So we need to (bitwise) shift the most significant byte to the left and add both. This code is for little endian because the first byte is the least significant one.

Comment: If you don't know the `<<` syntax: This is a bitwise shift operator. `ub2<<8` takes the bitwise represenation of `ub2` and shifts the bits 8 positions to the left.

Comment: Sure, `&` is a bitwise AND operator. So the bits of the result will be the corresponding bits of the two operands ANDed with each other: `b3[i] = b1[i] AND b2[i]`

Comment: I recommend going through [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) from oracle to read more about bitwise operations.

Comment: This only worked for me when I swapped ub2 and ub1 in the penultimate line (i.e. wrote this: "audio[i] = (ub1 << 8) + ub2;"). Could you exlpain why that is in plain English? I can't get my head around this whole byte to int conversion... A link with a simple explanation would do too.

Comment: There are two ways of ordering your bytes in storage (there are more, but those two are most often used): *Little Endian* and *Big Endian*. **Wikipedia has a good general article about it if you search for "Endianness".** Basically, in little endian, the **least significant byte** is stored in the first place. This code is written for little endian. You might work in a big endian environment where the **most significant byte** is stored first. In that case, you have to swap the two bytes (like you did) to get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

```
long value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < by.length; i++)
{
   value += ((long) by[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);
}
```

you can also create a sting and use the Integer valueOf or Integer constructor

Comment: thanks for the help. but i cant understand the line: value+=((long)by[i]&0xffl)<<(b*i); would you please explain it?

Comment: thas a algoritam if the 1st byte is the lsb

ps u can use a bunch of methods and approaches...remembered that a ByteBuffer can do the job also

Comment: i want to get an integer of 2 bytes. means, the size of the integer is 2 bytes. what should i do?

Comment: what i posted in the answer(if the first value of the array is the lsb) - that would be the fastest way...does it not function 4 u?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this inside a for loop. It worked for me (signed 16 bit samples, little endian).

```
//16 bit, litte endian (the first is the least significant)
int LSB=(int)b[i*2] & 0xff;
int MSB=(int)b[1+i*2] & 0xff;

x[i]=((MSB<<8)+LSB);
if((b[i*2+1)]&0x80)!=0)//Check the sign
       x[i]=-(65536-x[i]);
```